# How to compose regexes in code

Tags: regex

I am writing regex for the [IRC protocol abnf message format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#section-2.3.1).
The following is a short example of some of the regex I am writing.

```
// digit      =  %x30-39                 ; 0-9
// "[0-9]"
static const std::string digit("[\x30-\x39]");
```

I use previous definitions to form more complex ones, and this gets very complex, fast. Where I am having problems with, especially with more complicated regexes, is composing them:

```
// hexdigit = digit / "A" / "B" / "C" / "D" / "E" / "F"
// "[[0-9]ABCDEF]"
static const std::string hexdigit("[" + digit + "ABCDEF]");
```

A "hexdigit" is a "digit" or "hex-letter".

Note: I don't care that the RFC defines a "hexdigit" letter (ABCDEF) as only being uppercase. I am just going with what the RFC says and I don't plan on changing their requirements.

```
const std::regex digit(dapps::regex::digit);
assert(std::regex_match("0", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("1", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("2", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("3", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("4", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("5", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("6", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("7", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("8", digit));
assert(std::regex_match("9", digit));
assert(!std::regex_match("10", digit));
```

In the code above, matching a "digit" works as was intended in the abnf.

However, "hexdigit" is now illegal regex syntax:

```
[[0-9]ABCDEF]
```

Rather than

```
[0-9ABCDEF]
```

and trying to match with it won't work:

```
const std::regex hexdigit(dapps::regex::hexdigit);
assert(std::regex_match("0", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("1", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("2", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("3", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("4", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("5", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("6", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("7", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("8", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("9", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("A", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("B", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("C", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("D", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("E", hexdigit));
assert(std::regex_match("F", hexdigit));
assert(!std::regex_match("10", hexdigit));
```

Consequently, if I make "digit" not have the "single character in range selector", (`[ ]`) then you can't use "digit" to match a "digit".

I may just be going about this the wrong way entirely, so my question is:
Do I really need to keep both versions, the one with and without brackets, or is there an easier way altogether to compose regexes.

Comment: If I'm reading you correctly, are you trying to capture hex numbers?

Comment: Hex numbers are one of the 20 other composed regexes that are captured, yes. But the question is not about capturing hex numbers specifically, rather more about composing complex regexes from simpler ones.

Comment: Make a character class class that will hold `"0-9"` or `"ABCDEF"`. Implement a method to join another character class object. Implement a class that returns a regular expression (adds brackets, in this instance). Then you can do something like `std::regex_match("B", digits.or(a_to_f).regexp())`.

Comment: @Amadan interesting idea! Could I trouble you for a simple concrete example (such as the one you gave?)

Comment: Sorry, I'm really bad at C++. If you want a Ruby/Python/... example of the equivalent structure, sure. (While it's obvious you're using C++, you don't have the C++ tag.)

Comment: @Amadan it could be pseudocode, as an answer. Just not sure about the feasibility of your solution or how it is structured. Would you make "classes" for each regex string with these methods? or maybe some kind of inheritance heirarchy?

Comment: If you want to test hex digits, you can use `[0-9A-F]` (uppercase only), `[0-9a-f]` (lowercase only) or `[0-9a-fA-F]` (lowercase and uppercase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than meld the two character classes as you have attempted, which should have been:

```
[0-9ABCDEF]
```

construct an *alternation* - ie a logical `OR` - via the pipe char `|`, and bracket (non-grouping) the joined terms:

```
(?:[0-9]|[ABCDEF])
```

The benefit of this approach is you can join any two expressions this way, character class or otherwise, eg a digit or a whitespace:

```
(?:[0-9]|\s)
```

so it can be very generally applied.

---

Minor point: You can code `[ABCDEF]` as `[A-F]` and/or can make it case insensitive with `[A-Fa-f]`.

Comment: Do you think I should wrap every regex string in non-capture or capture groups?
Even simpler ones like matching a digit? Would this make a difference down the line when composing more complicated ones?
`(?:[\x30-\x39])` or `([\x30-\x39])` vs `[\x30-\x39]`

Comment: This is a good approach, the only problem is if you have repeating characters in joined classes. `[a-fa-fa-fa-f]` is harmless; `(?:[a-f])|(?:[a-f])|(?:[a-f])|(?:[a-f])` is potentially catastrophic. So some care needs to be exercised that alternatives are disjunct.

Comment: @Fran If you need to bracket up expressions, then you should use a non capturing group `(?:...)` for 3 reasons: 1) performance - they're slightly faster than capturing groups 2) if you ever introduce capturing groups into your DSL, the groups created for combining expression won't get in the way and 3) it's a negligible overhead for your code to do it

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I read your question right. If your concern is the "duplicated patterns" constants,  you can do it by:

```
static const std::string digit("0-9");
static const std::string hexdigit(digit + "ABCDEF");
static const std::string digit_range("[" + digit + "]");
static const std::string hexdigit_range("[" + hexdigit + "]");
```

or just keep the first 2, and have a util method like this (psuedo code):

```
static const std::string digit("0-9");
static const std::string hexdigit(digit + "ABCDEF");

string range_of(string... ranges) {
    string result = "[";
    for each range in ranges {
        result += range
    }
    result += "]";
    return result;
}
```

so that you can have different kind of range constants defined, and use by `std::regex pattern(range_of(hexdigit));` or even something like `std::regex pattern(range_of(digit, uppercase_alphabet, normal_punctuation));`

Comment: This solution wouldn't work. As I stated above, you wouldn't be able to match vs "digit" in the example you gave. `assert(std::regex_match("0", std::regex(digit)));` where you defined digit as: `static const std::string digit("0-9");`

Comment: I don't get what you mean by not working.  Content of `hexdigit_range` and `range_of(hexdigit)` are `[0-9ABCDEF]` and they are what what you are expecting isn't it?

Comment: right, but you would have to maintain multiple versions of the same regex, which is not optimal, whereas if you look at Bohemian's solution above, you can do it with only 1 regex.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "multiple versions".  Just by a little twist like `DIGITS = "0-9"; HEX_ALPHAS = "A-G";` with the "range_of()`, you can make up things like `range_of(DIGITS, HEX_ALPHAS)`.  You should be aware that @Bohemian's solution, although it works, it actually means different from what you was asking for.  And not to mention about the extra performance overhead of regex matching due to extra group and alternation

Comment: What I mean by multiple versions is that rather than having a single string, digit, you now have two: digit, and digit_range. You have twice the number of regex strings. As for performance differences, I am not sure. I guess it may come down to a memory vs performance problem as usual.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera please take a look on the 2nd approach I mentioned, for which with a `range_of` util function, which you do not need to keep "2 version" of constants.  By changing it to a template you may even avoid extra string creation everytime. (Honestly I don't see keeping 2 constants a problem, as long as when you are only required to change 1 constant if change is required)

Answer (score -1):

To get to the general format of an IRC message (no v3, as I see you don't consider tagged messages from v3) you can use [this simple regexp](https://regex101.com/r/eM5rH1/1):

```
^\s*(:[^ \n:]* )?([A-Za-z0-9]*)( [^ \n:]*)?( [^ \n:]*)?( [^ \n:]*)?( [^ \n:]*)?( [^ \n:]*)?( [^ \n:]*)?(:.*)?
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eM5rH1/1)

It allows you to dissect the message contents into its parts, allowing up to six different parameters to be matched and the **catchall** final one, preceded by `:`.

Comment: A comment on the reasons of the downvoting would be appreciated.